# Create minimum groups required to grant privileges users

Tags: algorithm, matrix, data-structures, graph, set

**Problem**

There are multiple users who require privileges to perform a certain task.
A user must not be granted more privileges than needed. Two or more groups can contain some common privileges.

e.g.

```
user1 -> p1 p2 p3
user2 -> p1    p3
user3 ->    p2
```

We need to create a minimum number of groups with privileges so that we can assign users to that group.

e.g.

```
group1 (p1 p3) -> user1, user2
group2  (p2)   -> user1, user3
```

---

---

Some test cases

case 1:

Input:

```
user1 -> p1
user2 ->    p2
user3 ->        p3
user3 ->           p4
```

Output:

```
group1(p1) -> user1
group2(p2) -> user2
group3(p3) -> user3
group4(p4) -> user4
```

---

case 2 :

Input:

```
user1 ->     p2  p3  p4
user2 ->     p2  p3  p4
user3 -> p1  p2  p3
user4 ->     p2  p3
```

Output:

solution1

```
group1(p1) -> user3
group2(p2,p3) -> user1,user2,user3,user4
group3(p4) -> user1, user2
```

solution2:

```
group1(p1) -> user3
group2(p2,p3,p4) -> user1,user2
group3(p2,p3) -> user3, user4
```

---

Comment: We don't want to give excessive permissions to the user.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming

- Users can be assigned to multiple groups
- Privileges can be assigned to multiple groups
- User can NOT be assigned to groups with unneeded privileges

Then

```
- Assign all privileges to one group
- Sort users into order of increasing number of privileges needed
- Loop over users 
  - Loop over groups
     - IF group contains user's unmet privileges
         - IF group contains no extra privileges
             - Assign user to group
  - ENDGROUPLOOP
  - If user's needs are NOT all met
     - Add new group with unmet privileges
     - Assign user to new group
  - ENDIF
- ENDUSERLOOP
```

Note that this will leave you with one group that contains every privilege.  If this has no user assigned to it, then you can assign this to an assumed ADMIN user, or discard it.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding ravenspoint's algorithm. Say we have,

```
user1 -> p1 p2 p3
user2 -> p1    p3
user3 ->    p2
```

From what I can see, the algorithm greedily first forms the group (p1, p2, p3). It means three groups become necessary:

```
group1(p1, p2, p3) -> user1
group2(p1, p3) -> user2
group3(p2) -> user3
```

It misses out on this solution with just two groups:

```
group1(p1, p3) -> user1, user2
group2(p2) -> user1, user3
```

I suspect the OP's problem is a variation of the Set Cover Problem and possibly NP-complete. If so, an approximate algorithm becomes necessary for big data sets but may not always reach an optimal solution.

Comment: Yes, agreed. I'll be dealing with larger data sets.